# using fetch in shared javascript module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have a shared javascript module that I am trying to import in both vue based frontend built with webpack and a node.js cli script. Initially the shared code was a part of the frontend (thus used `fetch`) and now I am trying to reuse it in the node.js cli script. So I stumbled upon `fetch` being unavailalble, which makes sense, but what I don't get is what are the options here. What I considered:

1. I tried importing `fetch` from `node-fetch` on the first line of the cli script via `import fetch from 'node-fetch'` and hoped that it will be exposed to the shared code imported later on but that does not work (ok that was a long shot and a naive hope). Is there a way to somehow provide globals to a script imported later on, or that is not an existent feature?
2. I tried conditional imports - defining some variable, e.g. `APP_ENV` in webpack and then conditionally import fetch but that also failed - webpack failed with `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level` when I did this:

```
if (APP_ENV !== 'browser') {
    import fetch from 'node-fetch'
}
```

Is the only option here using axios or some other request library in the shared code, or can I make either of options listed above work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the window object is defined
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window
If it's not defined you can asume that you are using Node

Assign the fetch function from node-fetch to a Node global variable
https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch'
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  global.fetch = fetch // you can use fetch() anywhere in Node (really useful for server side rendering)
}
```

Comment: @user2258152 ok thanks, did not know about the `global` keyword

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as I said in the question, my cli script which will never run in browser, is the one which is going to the import from `node-fetch` so even though you have a good point, this will work for my scenario, but thanks :)

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis - Ah, okay, I must have misunderstood. Have to say, though, that adding a global is generally an antipattern vs. making the module handle its own dependencies.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah, I can see how one can add up with multiple places defining a global and have a hell on earth :D That is why I said, this will work for me, but both answers gave me a lot of info :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder agreed we should avoid global variables as much as possible but sometimes it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a conditional import with [top-level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) and [dynamic `import()`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import), both of which are supported by Webpack.

For instance:

```
const localFetch = typeof fetch === "function"
    ? fetch
    : await import("node-Fetch").then(mod => mod.default);
```

That uses the global `fetch` if it exists, `node-fetch`'s default export if it doesn't (making the assumption that it's running on Node.js).

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep this in mind, but the `global` thingy seems to work nicely for my needs.